# Unexpected output of var_dump when string contains html

Tags: php, html, var-dump

I have an if statement that looks like this:

```
if($benchmark_one_name2 === "Russell 1000 Index"){
    $benchmark_one_name2 = "<span class='first'>Russell 1000 Index</span>";
    var_dump("this if statement is true");
}
var_dump($benchmark_one_name2);die;
```

Then I `var_dump` the value of `$benchmark_one_name2` right after to see if it has been set to `"<span class='first'>Russell 1000 Index</span>"`, but instead i get back this when I check the page:

```
string(25) "this if statement is true" string(45) "Russell 1000 Index"
```

I think it might have something to do with the HTML inside the string, but can't seem to find anything indicating that.

Comment: Check the source code of your page.  `Russell 1000 Index` is not 45 characters.  The `<span>` is being rendered as HTML.

Comment: Your browser is rendering html tags. Thats why the length is 45 yet the text is only 18 chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's outputting the value as you expect, but your browser is parsing the output as HTML. If you inspect the document you will see:

```html
string(25) "this if statement is true"
string(45) "<span class="first">Russell 1000 Index</span>"
```